# Best time to make a guess in an HMM with discounting?

Tags: probability, reference-request, hidden-markov-models

Consider a [hidden Markov model (HMM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) with $2$ states and $2$ outputs. The transition probabilities are $p_{ij}$, $i,j=1,2$ and output (emission) probabilities are $q_{ik}$, $i=1,2$, $k=1,2$. Assume an initial (prior) belief on the underlying state of $p$ (that is, $p = P(x_0 = 1)$).

Now, let's run the underlying Markov chain to generate a sequence of state realizations $x_0,x_1,\ldots$ (where $x_0$ is chosen from $\{1,2\}$ according to $p$). We assume that:

1. We don't see the true states, instead we see the output sequence $y_0,y_1,\ldots$ generated according to the probabilities $q_{ik}$.
2. We see a signal anytime the underlying chain **changes** states. That is, if $x_{t-1}\neq x_{t}$ then we see a signal $w_t=1$, otherwise $w_t=0$.

Imagine we get a discounted reward if we guess the true state (and zero if we make an incorrect guess). That is, if we make a correct guess at time $t$, then we get $\delta^t$ where $\delta\in(0,1)$ is given. Thus, our objective is to specify both a time $t$ and a guess $\hat x\in\{1,2\}$ such that $\delta^tP(x_t=\hat x)$ is maximized.

**Question:** What is the optimal rule determining this choice (as a function of $p$, $\delta$, $p_{ij}$'s, and $q_{ik}$'s)? That is, what's the mapping from the history of outputs ($y_0,y_1,\ldots$) and signals ($w_0,w_1,\ldots$) to a time-guess pair $(t,\hat x)$ that maximizes the discounted probability of being correct? Has anyone seen a similar problem in the literature?

Comment: Great question! As a first very rough estimate, I'd expect your posterior belief in the right state to go roughly as $1-c\lambda^t$ for some $\lambda\in(0,1)$, and maximizing $(1-c\lambda^t)\delta^t$ yields $t=-\log_\lambda c-\log_\lambda(1+\log_\delta\lambda)$. If this is negative, you should guess right away; if not, you should observe another state and then reevaluate $c$. I'm somewhat optimistic though that at least some of this can be worked out exactly in closed form.

Comment: @joriki Thanks for the hints! I've been trying to figure out how you got the form of your estimate $1-c\lambda^t$. Does this (the one minus bit) arise because you are taking the complement of guessing the wrong event (where $c\lambda^t$ represents the probability of guessing wrong)? I am able to write the posterior as a recursive update (as a function of the new output at each time) but I'm having a hard time getting it into the form you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps I should have emphasized more that this was just a "very first rough estimate". I don't expect the posterior to take this exact form; I just think that this should be the dominating term asymptotically. After a while, you should be almost sure which state is which, and further data should approximately geometrically decrease the remaining small uncertainty. But this is just a rough intuition, it could be way off. I'd like to work it out properly, I like the question, but that looks like a considerable project that I probably won't get around to before the end of the month.

Comment: @joriki Thanks for the additional explanation. That makes sense. I'm continuing to work on it. I will let you know if I make any progress! Thanks again for your help and intuition.